# Converting generic ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to convert:

`ArrayList<?> objects;` to `ArrayList<String>()` if you know `objects` only contains Strings?

Answer (score 7):

Yes; just cast it.
You will get a compile-time warning, because even though *you* know that, the compiler doesn't.

Beware that if someone else adds some other class to the list after you cast it, you will get exceptions when you try to use it.

This is only true because of type erasure.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<?> anonymList = null;
ArrayList<String> strings = (ArrayList<String>) anonymList;
```